# facebook canvas pages, fbml and javascript

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

I have a game that i have built for facebook in flash, but I have built a wrapper for it in html. I would like a JavaScript league table that once the user completed the game their score is sent to the db

The thing I would like- as soon as the game finishes the leage table is updated through javascript calls..

is this possible on fb canvas pages?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but someone may be able to help you [here](http://www.facebook.com/FanPageFactory?v=app_23744633048).

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not interfere with or forbid normal usage of javascript on canvas pages. So it should be possible.